# Can I get help converting an SQL query using JOINS to a ruby statement?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-8.4

I'm using ruby v2 rails v3.2, and postgreSQL v8.4.

I currently have this activerecord query:

```
@ct_a = DateTime.strptime('03-18-2015 22:08', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')
@ct_b = DateTime.strptime('03-20-2015 22:08', '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M')

events = Event.ips_events.all(conditions: ['timestamp >= ? AND timestamp <= ?', @ct_a, @ct_b ]).reverse
```

In SQL this query pretty much looks like this:

```
SELECT *
  FROM "event"
    WHERE (timestamp >= '2015-03-18 22:08:00' AND timestamp <= '2015-03-20 22:08:00') 
      ORDER BY event.timestamp desc;
```

I'd like to change the above `events` statement to a more efficient one using joins.

I've build the SQL query that gives me the desired output from four tables in one query.

```
SELECT "event".cid,
       "event".sid,
       "signature".sig_id,
       "signature".sig_name,
       "sig_class".sig_class_name,
       "signature".sig_priority,
       "signature".sig_rev,
       "signature".sig_sid,
       "signature".sig_gid,
       "iphdr".ip_src,
       "iphdr".ip_dst,
       "iphdr".ip_proto,
       "event".timestamp
  FROM "event" 
    JOIN signature ON (event.signature = signature.sig_id)
      JOIN sig_class ON (signature.sig_class_id = sig_class.sig_class_id)
        JOIN iphdr ON iphdr.cid = event.cid AND iphdr.sid = event.sid
          WHERE (timestamp >= '2015-03-18 22:08:00' AND timestamp <= '2015-03-20 22:08:00') 
            ORDER BY event.timestamp desc;
```

How can I do this in ruby on rails activerecord queries? I've tried `find_by_sql` but I only get back the events table, not joined like in raw SQL.

My models:

Event: Relation to Signature is Event.signature => Signature.sig_id

```
class Event < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | signature | timestamp
  #----------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :signature, :timestamp
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'event'
  has_many :sensors,
           :foreign_key => :sid
  has_many :signatures,
           :foreign_key => :sig_id,
           :primary_key => :signature
  has_many :ip_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
  has_many :tcp_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
  has_many :udp_hdrs,
           :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]

  def self.ips_events
    Event.order('event.timestamp desc').includes(:signatures,:ip_hdrs,:tcp_hdrs,:udp_hdrs)
  end
end
```

Signature: Relation to SigClass is Signature.sig_class_id => SigClass.sig_class_id

```
class Signature < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sig_id | sig_name | sig_class_id | sig_priority | sig_rev | sig_sid | sig_gid

  attr_accessible :sig_id, :sig_name, :sig_class_id, :sig_priority, :sig_rev, :sig_sid, :sig_gid
  self.table_name = 'signature'
  self.primary_key = :sig_id

  belongs_to :event,
             :foreign_key => :sig_id

  belongs_to :sig_class

  has_many :references,
           :through => :sig_references

  has_many :sig_references,
           :foreign_key => :sig_id
end
```

SigClass:

```
class SigClass < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sig_class_id | sig_class_name
  #-------------------------------
  attr_accessible :sig_class_id, :sig_class_name
  self.primary_key = :sig_class_id
  self.table_name = 'sig_class'
  has_many :signatures
end
```

IpHdr: Relation to Event is Event.cid and Event.sid => IpHdr.cid and IpHdr.sid

```
class IpHdr < ActiveRecord::Base
  # DB Schema
  # sid | cid | ip_src | ip_dst | ip_ver | ip_tos | ip_len | ip_id | ip_flags | ip_off | ip_ttl | ip_proto | ip_csum
  #-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  attr_accessible :sid, :cid, :ip_src, :ip_dst, :ip_ver, :ip_tos, :ip_len, :ip_id, :ip_flags, :ip_off,
                  :ip_ttl, :ip_proto, :ip_csum
  self.primary_keys = :sid, :cid
  self.table_name = 'iphdr'
  belongs_to :event,
             :foreign_key => [:sid, :cid]
end
```

Comment: you need to provide more info, concerning the models you have implemented

Comment: no, you need to provide the rails configuration of your models, what's in the app/models(event,signature,iphdr).rb files, concerning relations.

Comment: @xlembouras, how about now?

Comment: yes, it is complete now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Event.ips_events.joins([:ip_hdrs, {signatures: sig_class}])
```